Can't get Apache to redirect clients using a 308 instead of a 301
I have an Apache instance running on Ubuntu Server 22.04:
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
% apache2 -v    
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-07-17T18:57:26

This instance hosts a single virtual host ("foo").
I'm having a hard time trying to get Apache to redirect clients accessing /admin to the HTTPS version of the host using a 308 instead of a 301.
It doesn't matter what I put in the redirect flag (R=[]), the response's status code is always going to be 301.
Here's the contents of foo.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@dev-server.lan
        ServerName dev-server.lan

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts/foo

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/foo">
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/foo/admin">
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/admin/$1 [R=308,L]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Here's what happens:
% curl -v 'http://dev-server.lan/admin'
*   Trying 192.168.1.253:80...
* Connected to dev-server.lan (192.168.1.253) port 80 (#0)
> GET /admin HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev-server.lan
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2024 09:50:35 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
< Location: http://dev-server.lan/admin/
< Content-Length: 316
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://dev-server.lan/admin/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at dev-server.lan Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host dev-server.lan left intact

What I've tried:

[R=307,L], [R=302,L]: doesn't change anything; the response's status code is always going to be 301;

Looking for pesky .htaccess files; there are no .htaccess files nested under /var/www/html/vhosts/foo at all, besides a couple nested under /var/www/html/vhosts/foo/tickets (which by the way don't define any redirect):
% find /var/www/html/vhosts/foo -name '.htaccess'
/var/www/html/vhosts/foo/tickets/.htaccess
/var/www/html/vhosts/foo/tickets/pdfs/.htaccess


Looking for pesky RewriteRules; there are no RewriteRules defined in any .conf file under /etc/apache2 besides the one defined in foo.conf:
% find /etc/apache2 -type f -name '*.conf' -exec grep 'RewriteRule' {} +
/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo.conf:             RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/admin/$1 [R=308,L]



The access log only shows my attempts and doesn't shed a light:
192.168.1.253 - - [28/Sep/2024:11:23:17 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 525 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
192.168.1.253 - - [28/Sep/2024:11:50:35 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 525 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
192.168.1.253 - - [28/Sep/2024:14:55:34 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 525 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
192.168.1.253 - - [28/Sep/2024:15:00:43 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 525 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
192.168.1.253 - - [28/Sep/2024:15:03:40 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 525 "-" "curl/7.81.0"

The error log also only shows my attempts at restarting Apache after a config change:
[Sat Sep 28 15:03:37.617434 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 295999] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Sep 28 15:03:37.670005 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 296087] AH01906: dev-server.lan:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sat Sep 28 15:03:37.688283 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 296088] AH01906: dev-server.lan:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sat Sep 28 15:03:37.690899 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 296088] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 28 15:03:37.690926 2024] [core:notice] [pid 296088] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

What am I missing here?

Ok, turns out that trying to define the redirect in a Directory directive wasn't the best idea.
First off there's no real need to do that; it could simply be defined at the root level (this is a configuration for a local web server that I wrote a very long time ago. Either I was even noober then than I'm right now or I did it to keep things "visually organized". I don't know).
However what tipped me off was trying to follow the first (301) redirect using curl. That correctly restulted in the (308) redirect I was expecting.
Inspecting the first response more accurately, I noticed that the first (301) redirect was (again) to the HTTP version of the host (and not to the HTTPS version of the host), although, this time around, with an added trailing slash (facepalm).
At that point I realized that the first (301) redirect was being dispatched by Apache itself, and that trying to access http://dev-server.lan/admin wasn't enough to get into the Directory's scope to trigger the RewriteRule defined therein.
Moral of the story I refactored my whole .conf file in a (hopefully) more sensitive way (^/admin(/.*)?$ should correctly match either admin, admin/ or admin/ followed by any number of any character):
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@dev-server.lan
    ServerName dev-server.lan

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts/foo

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin(/.*)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=308,L]

    <Directory "/var/www/html/vhosts/foo">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

